# Web Scraping - Programatically submit and extract values of a form

Tags: .net, asp.net, web-scraping

I have very simple web form containing txtFirstName and txtLastName in aspx page. What I want to achieve programatically submit the form and to extract the values being sent in the form.
Through this extracted data, I want to do the web scraping (harvesting) and need to show in another page.

Answer (score 0):

You can programatically submit the form through javascript.

```
document.getElementById("form-id").submit();
```

In server-side retrieve the values from the Form collection in Request object,

```
string first = Request.Form["txtFirstName"]
```

Comment: Thanks for the reply. But how can this be used by another page which this string first OR txtFirstName for scraping.